# Splitting a string using space delimiters and a maximum length

Tags: python, string, split

I'd like to split a string in a similar way to `.split()` (so resulting in a list) but in a more intelligent way: I'd like it to split it into chunks that are up to 15 characters, but are not split mid word so:

```
string = 'A string with words'

[splitting process takes place]

list = ('A string with','words')
```

The string in this example is split between 'with' and 'words' because that's the last place you can split it and the first bit be 15 characters or less.

Comment: what to do with the words that are longer than 15 chars?

Comment: The string is heavily editted, so I can make sure the editor never uses words longer than 15 characters

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> string = 'A string with words'
>>> textwrap.wrap(string,15)
['A string with', 'words']
```

Comment: And the best part is that the package is generally already in

Answer (score 6):

You can do this two different ways:

```
>>> import re, textwrap
>>> s = 'A string with words'
>>> textwrap.wrap(s, 15)
['A string with', 'words']
>>> re.findall(r'\b.{1,15}\b', s)
['A string with ', 'words']
```

Note the slight difference in space handling.

Comment: Both good possibilities, but be aware that neither handles words longer than 15 characters very well `>>> s = 'A string with supercalifragilistic words'
>>> textwrap.wrap(s,15) 
['A string with s', 'upercalifragili', 'stic words']
>>> re.findall(r'\b.{1,15}\b', s)
['A string with ', ' words']
`

Comment: Define "very well."  If you're wrapping text and a word is longer than the width of your terminal, you very much do want to split that word into chunks of your terminal's width, because that width is a hard limit.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking to use a regex. The python [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re) module has a `split` function, but I think you would be better served by simply matching groups.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(.{,15})\s(.*$)', 'A string wth words')
[('A string wth', 'words')]
```

[Edit] sorry,  missed the point where you want multiple chunks. I was going to put a more complex regex in here, but the textwrap module cited above is made for this. I'll leave extending the regex as an exercise for you if you choose.

Comment: I like this because it doesn't break up or lose words longer than 15 characters, based on my very limited testing.